# css правило с псевдоклассами

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        #news :nth-child(4n) :not([id*="universal"]){ color:violet}
        </style>
    <div class="" id="news">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div class="" id="universal001">LINE</div>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
        <div>15</div>
        <div>16</div>
        <div>17</div>
        <div>18</div>
        <div>19</div>
        <div>20</div>
        <div>21</div>
        <div>22</div>
        <div>23</div>
        <div>24</div>
        <div class="" id="universal002">LINE</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div class="" id="universal003">LINE</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Почему не работает css правило?Или псевдоклассы нельзя сочетать? Задача "окрасить каждый 4 элемент, но не элемент с id , который содержит подстроку universal"

Comment: у Вас ни один id*="universal" всё равно не оказывается 4-м, так что условие с not в принципе лишнее :)

Comment: из-за id*="universal" смещается счетчик, цель - эл с id*="universal" добавить в исключения

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
#news :nth-child(4n):not([id*="universal"]){ color:violet}
</style>
```

пробел лишний

Comment: :not([id*="universal"]) не срабатывает

Comment: действует на 4 8 12 15 19 23, а не 4 8 12 16 20 24

Comment: @Mikhailz, я Вам в комментарии написал, почему не срабатывает - у Вас нет ни одного id*="universal" на 4-й позиции

Comment: https://codepen.io/Daaner/pen/zeoLXJ  все работает

Comment: "окрасить каждый 4 элемент, но не элемент с id , который содержит подстроку universal"

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в том, что вы указываете правило для блока с id="news", а не для вложенных в него элементам.
Должно быть так:

```
 #news div:nth-child(4n):not([id^="universal"]){ color: violet }
```

Comment: можно без div - @AndreyIvasko уже дал правильный ответ

Comment: можно без div, но условие :not([id*="universal"]) не срабатывает

Comment: если бы оно сработало, закрасились бы 4 8 12 16 20 24, а не 4 8 12 15 19 23

Comment: у вас не правильное представление что значит "каждый четвертый элемент".
Это как раз означает что закрасятся 4 8 12 16 20 24, но с условием если хоть один из этих элементов начинается с id^="universal", то он пропускается и закрашен не будет

Comment: @humster_spb срабатывает только 1 условие, исключение not() не засчитывается

Comment: @Mikhailz, исключения бы засчитывались, если бы id*="universal" попадал на 4-ю позицию. А то, чего Вы хотите добиться, с помощью css-исключения not не сделать - здесь js нужен

Answer (score 0):

То, чего Вы хотите добиться, с помощью css правила :not сделать не получится. Я набросал Вам примерный вариант, как достичь результата с jQuery:

```js
let i = 0; //задаём счётчик
$('#news div').each(function(){ //в цикле по всем дочерним элементам
  if($(this).text() != 'LINE') { //если элемент не LINE
    i++; //увеличиваем счётчик
  }
  if($(this).text() != 'LINE' && i%4 == 0) { //если элемент не LINE и он кратен четырем
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); //окрашиваем его
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="news">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div class="" id="universal001">LINE</div>
        <div>13</div>
        <div>14</div>
        <div>15</div>
        <div>16</div>
        <div>17</div>
        <div>18</div>
        <div>19</div>
        <div>20</div>
        <div>21</div>
        <div>22</div>
        <div>23</div>
        <div>24</div>
        <div class="" id="universal002">LINE</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div class="" id="universal003">LINE</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: я понимаю как решить эту задачу на jquery, проблема в том, что требуется решить только с помощью css

Comment: @Mikhailz, с помощью :not не получится - это правило не действует так, как Вы хотите. Оно всего лишь позволяет не применять свойства к какому-то элементу. Но изъять его из потока не позволяет. Можете вручную добавить нужным элементам какой-то класс и его покрасить - только такое решение на чистом css возможно

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо за помощь